# Replace local file by remote file

Tags: version-control, mercurial

How do I replace a local file by its latest version in the repository?

Is there also a way of replacing all local files which are conflicting with the corresponding files from the repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `hg update -C` and `hg revert` will do what you are looking for - replace a locally modified file with the clean version in the repository.  Personally I prefer `hg revert` but `hg up -C` will also do the job

#### hg revert

Some further details from the help for `hg revert`

```
With no revision specified, revert the specified files or directories to
the contents they had in the parent of the working directory. This
restores the contents of files to an unmodified state and unschedules
adds, removes, copies, and renames. If the working directory has two
parents, you must explicitly specify a revision.

Using the -r/--rev or -d/--date options, revert the given files or
directories to their states as of a specific revision. Because revert does
not change the working directory parents, this will cause these files to
appear modified. This can be helpful to "back out" some or all of an
earlier change. See "hg backout" for a related method.

Modified files are saved with a .orig suffix before reverting. To disable
these backups, use --no-backup.
```

Hope that helps

Chris

Comment: For s single file: `hg revert filename`

Answer (score 0):

svn update ?

Or delete your folder, and svn checkout...

Or try the option --force.